# Reorder table rows via Drag-and-Drop?

Tags: java, eclipse-plugin, drag-and-drop, swt, eclipse-rcp

I am new to Eclipse RCP/Plug-ins and SWT. I want to reorder table items via drag-and-drop.

I have a `TableViewer` which contains a table with my custom elements of type `ITask` (еach of my custom elements is wrapped in `TableItem`). All tutorials I found are about trees or dragging between different tables which is not what I need.

So I want to know how to reorder the table rows via drag-and-drop.

Comment: http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Java/0280__SWT/DragandDropinsideTable.htm

Comment: Are your TableItems are simple texts or POJOs? If ITask is implemented by POJO-s then the linked example is not enough for you.

Comment: @AdamHorvath my ITask elements are not just simple text elements. They have String name fields which are shown in the table so the user can see them but in fact they contain algorithms and other important fields.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a bit long, but you can make this work in your code with a few changes. I did not included the imports; Eclipse can do it for you automatically.

I used Spring's BeanUtils class but you can use any lib (or write your own) that can deepcopy POJOs. I assume that your ITask has a setOrder(int) method and is Serializable (and it qualifies for a POJO)

You need to create a Transfer-type for your ITask: SimpleObjectTransfer is IBM's code, from Eclipse GEF. You can Google/GrepCode it.

```
public final class TaskTransfer extends SimpleObjectTransfer {

public static final TaskTransfer INSTANCE = new TaskTransfer();

private TaskTransfer() {
}

@Override
protected String getTypeNamePrefix() {
    return "TASK_TRANSFER_FORMAT";
}
}
```

A ViewerDropAdapter:

```
public class MyDropAdapter<TM extends ITask> extends ViewerDropAdapter {

private final Class<TM> targetModelClass;
private List<TM> listOfModels;

protected MyDropAdapter(Viewer viewer, Class<TM> targetModelClass, List<TM> listOfModels) {
    super(viewer);
    this.listOfModels = listOfModels;
    this.targetModelClass = targetModelClass;
}

@Override
public boolean performDrop(Object arg0) {
    boolean ret = false;
    TM targetModel = targetModelClass.cast(determineTarget(getCurrentEvent()));

    if (targetModel != null) {
        if (List.class.isAssignableFrom(arg0.getClass())) {
            ret = processDropToTable(targetModel, arg0);
            getViewer().refresh();
        }
    }
    return ret;
}

public final boolean processDropToTable(TM targetModel, Object data) {

    List<TM> transferredModels = (List<TM>) data;
    List<TM> copyOfTransferredModels = transferredModels;

    switch (getCurrentOperation()) {
    case DND.DROP_COPY:
        copyOfTransferredModels = deepCopyBeanList(transferredModels, new String[]{});
        break;
    case DND.DROP_MOVE:
        // moving
        break;
    default:
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException(getCurrentOperation() + " is not supported!");
    }
    adjustPosition(transferredModels, copyOfTransferredModels, targetModel);

    return true;
}

private void adjustPosition(List<TM> transferredModels, List<TM> copyOfTransferredModels, TM targetModel) {
    int transferredObjectPosition = listOfModels.indexOf(transferredModels.get(0));
    listOfModels.removeAll(copyOfTransferredModels);
    addModelsToNewLocation(copyOfTransferredModels, targetModel, listOfModels, transferredObjectPosition);
    for (int i = 0; i < listOfModels.size(); i++) {
        int orderPosition = i * 10 + 10;
        listOfModels.get(i).setOrder(orderPosition);
    }
}

protected void addModelsToNewLocation(List<TM> transferredModels, TM targetModel, List<TM> targetList, int transferredObjectPosition) {
    switch (determineLocation(getCurrentEvent())) {
    case LOCATION_AFTER:
    case LOCATION_ON:
        int i;
        if (!transferredModels.contains(targetModel)) {
            i = targetList.indexOf(targetModel) + 1;
        } else {
            i = transferredObjectPosition;
        }
        targetList.addAll(i, transferredModels);
        break;
    case LOCATION_BEFORE:
        if (!transferredModels.contains(targetModel)) {
            i = targetList.indexOf(targetModel);
        } else {
            i = transferredObjectPosition;
        }
        targetList.addAll(i, transferredModels);

        break;
    case LOCATION_NONE:
    default:
        break;
    }
}

private List<TM> deepCopyBeanList(List<TM> transferredModels, String[] ignoreProperties) {
    List<TM> targetList = new LinkedList<TM>();

    for (TM element : transferredModels) {
        try {
            @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
            TM copy = (TM) element.getClass().newInstance();
            BeanUtils.copyProperties(element, copy, ignoreProperties);
            targetList.add(copy);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }
    return targetList;
}

@Override
public boolean validateDrop(Object arg0, int arg1, TransferData arg2) {
    boolean ret = false;
    for (Transfer t : new Transfer[]{TaskTransfer.INSTANCE}) {
        if (t.isSupportedType(arg2)) {
            ret = true;
            break;
        }
    }
    return ret;
}
}
```

A DragSourceListener

```
public class MyDragSourceListener implements DragSourceListener {
private final Viewer dragSourceViewer;
private final boolean multiObjectsEnabled;
private final Class<?> transferrableElementClass;
private Object[] draggedObjects;

public MyDragSourceListener(Viewer dragSourceViewer, boolean multiObjectsEnabled, Class<?> transferrableElementClass) {
    this.dragSourceViewer = dragSourceViewer;
    this.multiObjectsEnabled = multiObjectsEnabled;
    this.transferrableElementClass = transferrableElementClass;
}

@Override
public void dragStart(DragSourceEvent event) {
    Control source = ((DragSource) event.getSource()).getControl();

    draggedObjects = null;

    if (dragSourceViewer.getControl().equals(source)) {
        if (multiObjectsEnabled) {
            draggedObjects = ((StructuredSelection) dragSourceViewer.getSelection()).toArray();
        } else {
            draggedObjects = new Object[]{((StructuredSelection) dragSourceViewer.getSelection()).getFirstElement()};
        }
    }
    event.doit = draggedObjects.length > 0 && transferredDataIsSupported();
}

private boolean transferredDataIsSupported() {
    boolean ret = true;
    for (Object o : draggedObjects) {
        if (o == null || !transferrableElementClass.isAssignableFrom(o.getClass())) {
            ret = false;
            break;
        }
    }
    return ret;
}

@Override
public void dragSetData(DragSourceEvent event) {
    event.data = Arrays.asList(draggedObjects);
}

@Override
public void dragFinished(DragSourceEvent event) {
    if (event.detail != DND.DROP_NONE) {
        dragSourceViewer.refresh();
    }
    draggedObjects = null;
}
}
```

And place a code somewhat like this in your View:

```
List<ITask> tasks = new WritableList(new ArrayList<ITask>(), ITask.class);

// Let's say tableViewerTasks is your TableViewer's name

DragSource sourceTasks = new DragSource(tblTasks, DND.DROP_MOVE);
sourceTasks.setTransfer(new Transfer[]{TaskTransfer.INSTANCE});
sourceTasks.addDragListener(new MyDragSourceListener(tableViewerTasks, true, ITask.class));

DropTarget targetTasks = new DropTarget(tblTasks, DND.DROP_MOVE);
targetTasks.setTransfer(new Transfer[]{TaskTransfer.INSTANCE});
targetTasks.addDropListener(new MyDropAdapter<ITask>(tableViewerTasks, ITask.class, tasks));
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Could I use `LocalSelectionTransfer` instead of creating my own transfer type?